# Give permissions to folders SharePoint Online PowerShell

Tags: powershell, office-365

I created a folder in a SharePoint Online library.

```
Add-SPOFolder -Name NewFolder -Folder _catalogs/new
```

This works fine. But how can I give `Full control` permissions for a user on this folder?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use CSOM via PowerShell to can create a Folder and assign a user permission as the following :

- Specify the user.

> ```
> $usr = $Web.EnsureUser('i:0#.f|membership|'+$email)
>     Write-Host $usrRole.Description
>     $clientContext.Load($usr)
>     $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
> ```

- Define the Full control Role

> ```
> $role = $web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName('Full Control')
> $usrRole = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionBindingCollection($clientContext)
> $usrRole.Add($role)
> $clientContext.Load($role)
> $clientContext.Load($usrRole)
> ```

- Break Inheritance, and assign the permission

> ```
> $folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($false, $true)
> $clientContext.Load($folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add($usr, $usrRole))
> $folder.Update()
> $clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
> ```

Check the bundle script at  [SharePoint Online CSOM PowerShell Script to create folders and add permissions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178984/sharepoint-online-csom-powershell-script-to-create-folders-and-add-permissions)