# SharePoint Online CSOM PowerShell Script to add permissions

Tags: powershell, csom, script

I am rather new to this place I would like to ask a question about CSOM.
I'd like to set unique permissions for a particular folder in a particular document, then I found the following URL on the internet.

[SharePoint Online CSOM PowerShell Script to create folders and add permissions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/178984/sharepoint-online-csom-powershell-script-to-create-folders-and-add-permissions)

After referring to and executing the inside command, the following error occurred.

> ERROR: Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s):
>   "Cannot add a role assignment with empty role definition binding
>   collection."

[image]

How can I resolve the above error?

Comment: Did you check your user and userrole variable aren't null? This error seems to be with empty role.